# Curl $_GET in function

Tags: php, curl

I do have a script:

```
<?php 

    $ch = curl_init($theUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $dirname . $cookie_txt);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);
```

This one is working pretty good. If I now do this:

```
<?php 
function startCurl() {
     $ch = curl_init($theUrl);
     ....
      parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);
 }

 startCurl();
```

Now the variable $_GET is false. Why? How can I change it. I think $_GET is global.

Thanks for an answer.

Comment: Can you try with `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Yep, but `$argv` is not.

Comment: But if I do global $argv; it is not working as well

Comment: Pass `$argv` as a parameter instead of trying to use `global`. Using `global` is bad practice!

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a new global variable

$argv is a global variable, but it's not suggest use in here ,you need pass the value for this function

Comment: `$argv`is a `global` variable, it's just not a `superglobal` like `$_GET`